# Error: No se pudo encontrar la función str_to_title

Tags: r, estructuras-de-datos, markdown

Tengo el siguiente código:

````
```{r chunk 6}

# Treiem els espais en blanc (davant i darrere) del dataframe continguts en les següents variables:

rawdata$city <- trimws(rawdata$city)
rawdata$sex <- trimws(rawdata$sex)

##Els noms de les ciutats contenen la primera lletra de cada paraula en majúscula.

rawdata$city <- str_to_title(rawdata$city)
rawdata$city <- sub("De","de",rawdata$city)

##Els valors de genènere s'estandaritzen com M i F.

#Utilitzant table(rawdata$sex) veiem quines son les categories de la variable sexe i veiem que són M i F.

#Un cop vistes les categories, fem que la variable "sex" sigui sempre en majúscula. 

rawdata$sex <- toupper(rawdata$sex)

##El nivell d'estudis s'estandaritza passant el número a un caràcter: 1(N),2(P),3(S),4(U).

rawdata$educ_level <- factor(rawdata$educ_level,levels=c(1:4),labels=c("N","P","S","U"))

##El tipus de treball s'estandaritza amb la següent abreviatura: 1(C), 2(PC).

rawdata$job_type <- factor(rawdata$job_type,levels=c(1:2),labels=c("C","PC"))

```
````

Cuando voy a ejecutarlo y exportarlo con **RMakdown** a **PDF**, me sale el siguiente error:

```
Error in str_to_title(rawdata$city) : 
  no se pudo encontrar la función "str_to_title"
Calls: <Anonymous> ... handle -> withCallingHandlers -> withVisible -> eval -> eval

Ejecución interrumpida
```

Sin embargo, si ejecuto únicamente el **chunk** en cuestión todo va bien.

¿Alguna idea? Muchas gracias.

Comment: Posiblemente no hayas importado `stringr`, agrega a tu código `library(stringr)` y nos cuentas.

Comment: Ya lo hice y sigue sin funcionar...

Comment: Bien, prueba invocar la función agregando también el paquete, es decir: `stringr::str_to_title() ` por ej `stringr::str_to_title(rawdata$city)`

Comment: El comando library(stringr) debe estar en un chunk al inicio del Rmarkdown. No basta con cargarlo en la consola. Debe estar dentro del markdown.